# ¿Cómo hacer una interfaz de aplicación?

Tags: java, layout

Este script es un programa para preguntarme palabras de francés a mi mismo  y me gustaría si se podría hacer una interfaz para el programa, y si se podría como.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palabras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner wordL= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner wordR = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner answer= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL1= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR1= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL2= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR2= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL3= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR3= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL4= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR4= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println(wordL2 + " -> ");

        String answer2= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer2.equals(wordR2)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }
        System.out.println(wordL3 + " -> ");

        String answer3= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer3.equals(wordR3)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }
        System.out.println(wordL4 + " -> ");

        String answer4= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer4.equals(wordR4)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }
        System.out.println(wordL1 + " -> ");

        String answer1= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer1.equals(wordR1)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }

        System.out.println("This was the exam, well done.");
}
```

Comment: Lo mas facil seria usar [swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) aunque ya va a caer en desuso. Mejor [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784) O puedes intentar movil con [Android](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)

Comment: Puedes hacer una interfaz gráfica con la ayuda de la IDE NetBeans, donde tienes la posibilidad de abrir un archivo JFrame dentro de tu proyecto, aquí podrás hacer uso de herramientas como botones, textfield, etiquetas (JLabel), entre más herramientas que necesites para tu interfaz. Entonces, para que logres tu interfaz gráfica solamente es cambiar tus entradas por teclado de la clase Scanner por los textfield y es la misma lógica que tienes en tu proyecto, de igual manera para mostrar en pantalla algún valor o contenido, si lo hacías con System.ou.println ahora lo harás con JLabel en la posici

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo buscar información sobre [Swing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(biblioteca_gr%C3%A1fica)) y/o [JavaFX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), y decidas cual quieres usar: (Ambas son bibliotecas gráficas que sirven para crear interfaces, entre otras cosas)

- Swing tiene más información online en general, es más facil buscar como hacer cualquier cosa.
- JavaFX está mejor actualizado, más novedoso y más potente (en casi todos los aspectos).

Busca información sobre ambos y empieza a hacer interfaces simples para aprender:

- [Ejemplo simple en Swing](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/)
- [Ejemplo simple en JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm)

Si después tienes preguntas más concretas vuelve, y seguro que hay gente (Yo incluido) que estará encantada de ayudar.

Comment: la pregunta es amplia, pero tu respuesta consigue dejar el tema bastante bien cerrado el tema.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos!